# PHP mail script not sending textarea and duplicating everything else in body

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

Im trying to send an e-mail with the following script I've made. But seem to encounter a weird problem that I need help with.

**The mail script**

```
// Get field values.
$name = strip_tags($_POST["name"]);
$email = strip_tags($_POST["email"]);
$message = $_POST["msg"];

// Check if e-mail address is valid.
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  // Set e-mail and subject.
  $to = "mail@mydomain.dk";
  $subject = "You have a new message.";

  // Set header values.
  $headers  = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

  // Set request body.
  $message  = "<html>";
  $message .=   "<body>";
  $message .=     "<p><b>From:</b><br>" . $name . "</p>";
  $message .=     "<p><b>Email:</b><br>" . $email . "</p>";
  $message .=     "<p><b>Message:</b><br>" . $message . "</p>";
  $message .=   "</body>";
  $message .= "</html>";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  echo "Your email was sent!";

} else {

  echo "Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.";

}
```

**The HTML**

```
<form id="contact-form" data-toggle="validator" data-disable="true" role="form">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="name">Navn</label>
                 <input type="text" name="name" id="contact-name" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please provide a valid name." required>
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                 <input type="email" name="email" id="contact-email" class="form-control" data-minlength="5" data-error="Please provide a valid e-mail address." required>
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="message">Your message:</label>
                  <textarea name="msg" id="contact-email" data-minlength="10" data-error="Your message must be at least 10 characters long." class="form-control" required></textarea>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <button id="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                 <div id="success"></div>
               </div>
             </form>
```

**The Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#success').css('display', 'none');

  $('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/form.php",
      data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
      type: 'POST',
      statusCode: {
        500: function(data) {
          $('#success').css('display', 'none');
          $('#success').css('color', '#A94442');
          $('#success').html('Your message was not sent.');
          $('#success').fadeIn(200);
        },
        404: function(data) {
          $('#success').css('display', 'none');
          $('#success').css('color', '#A94442');
          $('#success').html('Your message was not sent.');
          $('#success').fadeIn(200);
        },
        200: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $('#success').css('display', 'none');
          $('#success').css('color', '#74C274');
          $('#success').html('Your message was sent.');
          $('#success').fadeIn(200);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The e-mail is sent and received, but the textarea is not getting sent through, and it seems to sent the "email" and "name" field twice in the message body.

**The e-mail output looks like this:**

```
From:
Someone

Email:
someone@someone.com

Besked:

From:
Someone

Email:
someone@someone.com
```

Help will be very much appreciated. Have been trying to fix this for hours now.

Comment: Could you show the output that `$("#contact-form").serialize()` returns from the console maybe?

Comment: your code seems OK. try to remove <html> and <body> tags. send only <p> tags.

Comment: Jacques Marais, the console output looks like this: name=test&email=test%40test.com&msg=this+is+a+test+message

Comment: Mohammad Ahmad, it didnt work. Same result.

Comment: Thank you for helping me tho. :)

Comment: Please check Id you are using "#contact-email" are same for email and message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is located here :

```
$message .=     "<p><b>Message:</b><br>" . $message . "</p>";
```

You are using the same variable for the message to be sent and the message received by your PHP.

This code will be working :

```
// Get field values.
$name = strip_tags($_POST["name"]);
$email = strip_tags($_POST["email"]);
$message_text = $_POST["msg"];

// Check if e-mail address is valid.
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  // Set e-mail and subject.
  $to = "mail@mydomain.dk";
  $subject = "You have a new message.";

  // Set header values.
  $headers  = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

  // Set request body.
  $message  = "<html>";
  $message .=   "<body>";
  $message .=     "<p><b>From:</b><br>" . $name . "</p>";
  $message .=     "<p><b>Email:</b><br>" . $email . "</p>";
  $message .=     "<p><b>Message:</b><br>" . $message_text . "</p>";
  $message .=   "</body>";
  $message .= "</html>";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  echo "Your email was sent!";

} else {

  echo "Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.";

}
```